please help me solve this complex integral using limit
Let $ F(w)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x-w}dx $,
then for $a(real) \in (0,1) $,
solve $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^{+}}(F(a+ih)-F(-a-ih)) $,
i know the complex analysis but cannot assume its value.
Is $-a-ih$ contained in integral domain?
if not, Would $ F(-a-ih) $ be zero and so $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^{+}}F(a+ih)=\pi i $?
for grammatical errors, please forgive me.

$F$ is defined on $\mathbb C\setminus [0,1]$.

O.K. it might be no problem! anyway, thank you for your notification :) i inserted h to make argument has non-vanishing imaginary part.

In fact, this problem appeared in recent entrance exam of graduate school. i wrote it as $\pi i $ making a mistake but very happy to know right answer anyway :)

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Hereafter, $\ds{\bracks{\cdots}}$ is an $\ds{\it Iverson's\ Bracket}$.
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\left.\on{F}\pars{a + \ic 0^{+}} - \on{F}\pars{-a - \ic 0^{+}}\right\vert_{\ a\ \in\ \pars{0,1}}}
\\[5mm] = &
\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over x - \pars{a + \ic 0^{+}}} -
\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over x - \pars{-a - \ic 0^{+}}}
\\[5mm] = & \ 
\phantom{xx}\braces{{\rm P.V.}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over x - a} + \ic\pi\int_{0}^{1}\delta\pars{x - a}\dd x}
\\ & \ -
\braces{{\rm P.V.}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over x + a} - \ic\pi\int_{0}^{1}\delta\pars{x + a}\dd x}
\\[5mm] = & \
\phantom{x\,}{\rm P.V.}\int_{-a}^{1 - a}\ {\dd x \over x}\ +\ \ic\pi\ \overbrace{\bracks{0 < a < 1}}^{\ds{= 1}}
\\ &-\require{cancel}
{\rm P.V.}\int_{a}^{1 + a}\ {\dd x \over x}\ -\ \ic\pi\cancel{{\bracks{0 < -a < 1}}}
\\[5mm] = & \ \int_{a}^{1 - a}{\dd x \over x} -
\int_{a}^{1 + a}{\dd x \over x} + \pi\ic
\\[5mm] = & \ \bbx{\color{#44f}{\ln\pars{1 - a \over 1 + a} + \pi\ic,\qquad \color{black}{a \in \pars{0,1}}}} \\ &
\end{align}
Note: A well-known identity is used. Namely,
\begin{align}
& \int_{p}^{q}{\on{f}\pars{x} \over x - r \pm \ic 0^{+}}\dd x
\\[5mm] = & \
{\rm P.V.}\int_{p}^{q}{\on{f}\pars{x} \over x - r }\dd x \mp \int_{p}^{q}\on{f}\pars{x}\ic\pi\delta\pars{x - r}\dd x
\end{align}

Nice calculation! but i need some time to understand your sincere note perfectly. As far as i know, P.V. is a limit value of "from -t to + t" where t is integral variable. but what is the reason to attach P.V. beside "from 0 to 1"? and from there, i can see change of variable $x \pm a \rightarrow x $ and i was able to keep up.

$$
{\rm P.V.}\int_{-a}^{1 - a}{{\rm d} x \over x} = {\rm P.V.}\int_{-a}^{a}{{\rm d} x \over x} + {\rm P.V.}\int_{a}^{1 - a}{{\rm d} x  \over x}
$$
The first one vanishes out. The second one doesn't need ${\rm P.V.}$ anymore.

I just added a final note -at the very end-.

You give me much information and problem solving skill. thanks a lot again!
